# One question about K-moduli space of smooth plane conic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, k-stability

I am reading Ascher-Devleming-Liu's paper "Wall crossing for K-moduli spaces of plane curves" example 4.5 (2) (b) [ADL 19](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.04576) and l have some confusions.

From Li-Sun's paper "Conical Kähler-Einstein metric revisted" [LS 12](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5011), we know ($\mathbb{P}^2$, $\frac{3}{4}$$C$) is K-semistable and admit a special degeneration to the K-polystable pair ($\mathbb{P}$(1,1,4), $\frac{3}{4}$$C_0$) where $C$ is a smooth plane conic curve and $C_0$ = ($z$ = 0) with $[x,y,z]$ the projective coordinates of $\mathbb{P}$(1,1,4).

If $(X, \frac{3}{4}D)$ is K-semistable with $X$ non-smooth, then by [LWX 18](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.03393) it admits a special degeneration to ($\mathbb{P}$(1,1,4), $\frac{3}{4}$$C_0$). Because of K-semistable pair $(X, \frac{3}{4}D)$ and its degeneration to ($\mathbb{P}$(1,1,4), $\frac{3}{4}$$C_0$), l know $X$'s $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein index is 2 and $D $ is smooth.

My question is how to use these outcomes to deduce $(X, \frac{3}{4}D)$ $\cong$
($\mathbb{P}$(1,1,4), $\frac{3}{4}$$C_0$). Any comments are welcome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to see that $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$, both using the fact that $X$ isotrivially degenerates to $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$.

(1) By Hacking's paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0310354.pdf, Theorem 8.3, one knows that $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$ has no locally trivial deformations, and has one parameter deformation for its only singularity which smooth out the singularity and get $\mathbb{P^2}$. Since $X$ is non-smooth, it has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$.

(2) Notice that $\mathbb{P}^2$ isotrivially degenerates to $X$, and $X$ isotrivially degenerates to $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$. Thus we have
$$
\dim \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^2) \leq \dim \mathrm{Aut}(X) \leq \dim \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)).
$$
This can be seen by a standard Hilbert scheme argument: embed all three into a large projective space $\mathbb{P}^N$ using a sufficiently divisible power of anti-canonical divisors, and look at their $PGL_{N+1}$ orbits in the Hilbert scheme of $\mathbb{P}^N$. Then the assumption on isotrivial degenerations gives inclusions of orbit closures $\overline{PGL_{N+1} \cdot [\mathbb{P}^2]} \supseteq \overline{PGL_{N+1} \cdot [X]} \supseteq \overline{PGL_{N+1} \cdot [\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)]} $. Then we have an inequality on the dimension of orbits which implies the above inequality on dimension of automorphism groups.

Then one can compute the dimension of automorphisms and observe that the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$ has one more dimension than that of $\mathbb{P}^2$. Thus the dimension of automorphism group of $X$ is either equal to that of $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$  or of $\mathbb{P}^2$. In either case, the above Hilbert scheme argument implies that $X\cong \mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$ or $X\cong \mathbb{P}^2$, while the latter case cannot happen as $X$ is singular.

Once you show $X\cong \mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$, the fact that $C_0$ does not pass through the singularity implies that so is $D$, which then shows the pairs are the same after a suitable change of coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer.